# Printer Canon MP250 shows job as complete but no page is printed out

Tags: 16.04, printing, canon

I have a Canon MP250 installed under Ubuntu 16.04. When I print a test page everything works fine. However when printing a file the job says it's completed but no page is printed out.

This is the status I get for lpstat

```
$ lpstat -d -p
system default destination: MP250-series
printer MP250-series is idle.  enabled since Wed 29 Mar 2017 09:08:02 PM UYT
    Finished page 2...
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?